# On Series Expansion and Probability Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, power-series, taylor-expansion, poisson-distribution

Consider the expansion of $e^{x}$,
$$e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^3}{3!}+\cdots+\frac {x^n}{n!}+\cdots $$
Note that each term of the expansion on RHS, when divided by the closed form (LHS), gives the Poisson distribution, $Y \sim \text{Pois}(x)$ i.e.
$$P(Y=n) = e^{-x}\cdot \frac {x^n}{n!}$$

Now consider the expansion of $\frac 1{1-x}$ (or, conversely, the infinite sum of a geometric progression),
$$\frac 1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}+\cdots$$
Each term of the expansion on RHS, when divided by the closed form (LHS), gives the Geometric Distribution $Y \sim \text{Geo}(x)$, i.e.
$$P(Y=n) = x^{n-1} (1-x)$$

> **Questions**
>
> Are there other similar discrete probability distributions where the probability of random variable $Y$ taking on value $n$ is given by e.g. the $n$-th term in the series expansion of a function divided by the closed form of the function?
>
> Conversely, does this mean that every function with a series expansion has a corresponding discrete probability distribution? Which are the more commonly known functions and their corresponding probability distributions?

Obviously this will not work for series with alternating signs e.g. $\ln x$ or $\sin x$.

Any views or comments on this topic would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Try to list all discrete distributions you know, and then try to see whether something interesting comes up, looking at their probability.

Answer (score 1):

For any probability distribution $p$ supported on the nonnegative integers, the series
$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) z^n$ defines the [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) of $p$.
It is analytic on (at least) $|z| < 1$.  If $X$ is a random variable with distribution $p$, $f(z) = \mathbb E[z^X]$.

If $f(z)$ is analytic in $|z|<1$ with $f(1) = 1$ and all its Maclaurin series coefficients are nonnegative, then $f(z)$ is the probability generating function of a probability distribution supported on the nonnegative integers.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The question is whether there are any other examples of familiar functions which correspond to a familiar probability distribution, e.g. the exponential function corresponding to the Poisson distribution.

Comment: The Wikipedia page I cited has a couple of examples of pgf's.  Nearly every discrete probability distribution familiar enough to have a Wikipedia page will have its pgf listed on that page.